# One-sided Gauss-Hermite quadrature

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

The [Gauss-Hermite quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature) is useful for numerically evaluating integrals of the following form:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$

which yields

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\approx\sum_{i=1}^nw_if(x_i),$$

where $x_i, i=1,\ldots,n$ are the roots of the physicists' version of Hermite polynomial $H_n(x)$, and weights $w_i=\frac{2^{n-1}n!\sqrt{\pi}}{n^2[H_{n-1}(x_i)]^2}$.

I am wondering if a similarly convenient quadrature is known for an integral of the following form:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$

where $f(x)$ is not symmetric around the origin.

Comment: Hi, you may find the following paper useful: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1969-23-107/S0025-5718-1969-0247744-3/S0025-5718-1969-0247744-3.pdf

Comment: Indeed, this is very useful!  Thank you for pointing me to this paper.  The citations pointing to it are also interesting.